# Get attachement binary of SP.File object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, sp.js

I'm facing with a problem in retrieving binary of attachement list item. I use this code to get the value:

```
var appweburl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
    + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

var hostweburl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;

var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

executor.executeAsync({
    url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Lists/myList/Attachments/1/myImage.jpeg')/$value?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
    method: "GET",
    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.body);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    },
});
```

But it returns me back this error:

```
    GET "https://mySharePointAddress/Site/Subsite/web/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/Lists/myList/Attachments/1/myImage.jpeg')/$value?@target=%27https://mySharepointAddress/Site%27 403 (Forbidden)

    Uncaught ReferenceError: ret is not defined
    at Function.SP.RequestExecutorInternalSharedUtility.$13 (SP.RequestExecutor.js:2)
    at Function.SP.RequestExecutor.internalProcessXMLHttpRequestOnreadystatechange (SP.RequestExecutor.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (SP.RequestExecutor.js:2)
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution of my problem using jquery ajax, thank's to Henry Algus
http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/